# Disable UIScrollView scrolling out of content

Tags: ios, swift

When my UIScrollView is on contentOffset = (0,0) I try to scroll it left outside of the content. Then content moves right, there is empty space on begin of scrollview and it returns with animation to (0,0) at the end of scrolling.
How to disable this scrolling out of content?

Comment: `yourScrollView.bounces = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `bounces` property of `UIScrollView` to false to disable both horizontal and vertical bouncing. To disable horizontal bounce set `false` to `alwaysBounceHorizontal` and for vertical bounce set `false` to `alwaysBounceVertical`.

```
scrollView.bounces = false
```

or

[image]